# Prove that a matrix is positive definite and symmetrical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem I am working on is defined as the following. Given a nxp matrix X of numbers. Show that $X^tX$ is positive definite and symmetrical. I cannot work our how this must be a consequence of the definition of X. I assume it is true since it is given as a problem, and I cannot find a counterexample either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the author meant positive semidefinite, or specified something about the rank of $X$.

**Hint:**

Note that a matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite iff $v^TAv \geq 0$ for all vectors $v$.  Note that $v^TX^TXv = (Xv)^T(Xv)$.

As for symmetry: note that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to work something out. One thing that is certain is that $X^TX$ is symmetric, because $(X^TX)^T = X^T(X^T)^T = X^TX$. By the Spectral theorem, it follows that $X^TX$ can be decomposed into matrices of eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Now I should be able to show $v^TX^TXv \geq 0$ for all vectors v I think. 

And thank you Karl (below) for providing the hint of transpose of $X^TX$

Comment: @user29163 it's much easier than that.  Setting $y = Xv$, note that $v^TX^TXv = y^Ty = \|y\|^2$, which is necessarily non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
in English it is *symmetric matrix*.
There must be some additional  conditions you didn't tell.
But if they are fulfilled:

What did you do yourself?

What is the transpose of $X^tX$? ( Wikipedia is your friend, if you don't know)

What is for a vector $a$ then $Xa$ and what is $a^tX^t$ (if the not by you provided conditions are fulfilled)?

From this you should be able to get the answer.

Ciao

Karl